# Create Chart using PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table - request_events with three fields;  request_eventsid,datetime,type.this table will track all the activities of my website day wise and also type wise.thus,type may be 1 or 2.I need to display an open-chart for understanding the progress.So I need to retrieve the ratio of type2/type1 as input day wise.How can I get all these input for last 30 days from this table.Please give me some idea....It already kill my week end.Please help me

Comment: perhaps adding some spaces/formatting to your question would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get 30-day type-wise event counts with a query something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(type) FROM request_events 
    WHERE 
    datetime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    GROUP BY type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [smart chart maker](http://mysqlreports.com). it can help you generate any charts that is fed directly from your MySQL database,  it does support a data filter option, from which you can specify the exact data you want to display in your chart, and finally it supports aggregation functions such as "count, sum, avg,..etc)

[image: Using the count aggregation function]

You can use smart chart maker for any types of charts. For more information please watch this [video tutorial](http://mysqlreports.com/charttour.html)

[image]